# Trying to count from 10 to the input value provided and columns provided in Python but not getting it. I basically want like 5 numbers on top etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, juniper

```
counter = 10
numbers = int(input("Enter a number between 10 and 99: "))
column = int(input("How many columns would you like? "))
for num in range(10, numbers):
    for col in range(column):
        counter += 1
    print(num + 1, end= ' ')
print()
```

Trying to count from 10 to the input value provided and columns provided in Python but not getting it. I basically want like 5 numbers on top, 5 on bottom etc.

Comment: what is the purpose of counter += 1 in the inner for loop?

Comment: could you add some examples for different inputs to understand what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counter = 10
numbers = int(input("Enter a number between 10 and 99: "))
column = int(input("How many columns would you like? "))
output_string = ""

col_counter = 0
while (counter <= numbers):
    output_string += str(counter)+" "
    counter += 1
    col_counter += 1
    if(col_counter == column):
       print(output_string)
       output_string=""
       col_counter = 0
print(output_string)
```

This should do it just fine

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I wanted to use the for loop but this works.

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this?

```
>>> n = 30 # numbers
>>> c = 3 # columns
>>> for i in range(10, n+1):
...     print(i, end='\t')
...     if (i - 10) % c == 0:
...         print()
... else:
...     print()
...
10      11      12
13      14      15
16      17      18
19      20      21
22      23      24
25      26      27
28      29      30

>>>
```

Comment: I believe OP wants 10 to `n`, not `n+10`